# Is there a clever way to debug Python code, when writing in Atom?

Tags: python, debugging, atom-editor

I recently switched from Eclipse/PyDev to Atom. One downside is that copypasting

```
import pdb
pdb.set_trace()
```

and aligning it with indentaion is a turnoff (which slows me down in different ways as it makes me use a lot of unnecessary logging which clutters things in different ways).

Is there any clever way to set breakpoints? Maybe something web-based like [node-inspector](https://github.com/node-inspector/node-inspector) to easily use it on remote machines? Maybe an Atom package? Maybe a macro?

Comment: @janbrohl Thanks for the suggestion. I didn't know they have an open source version. I'll give it a try. Do you have experience if it works if the code is actually running inside of a docker container (guess one needs remote debugging capabilities etc.)?

Comment: I don't know but the page about the extension mentions remote debugging support and there is a section about it in the [wiki](https://github.com/DonJayamanne/pythonVSCode/wiki)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an atom package called [python-debugger](https://atom.io/packages/python-debugger), which can be used for debugging in python.